# Rails 4 Form Partial Not Rendering Submitted Data Immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Probably a very simple problem I'm overlooking.  I'm building a feature similar to Facebook's "home" page for logged in users. A user can post topics in one form, and that form works perfectly.

There is a comment form under each posted topic.  When a user enters a comment and clicks the submit button the comment is created, but it is not shown unless I manually refresh the page.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

_form.html.haml

```
= form_for [topic, Comment.new], remote: true do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.text_area :body, rows: 2, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Make a comment"
    = f.submit "Post", class: 'f-button primary f-fw-bold post-btn'
```

I have tried using @topic for this form as well but get the error: undefined method `comments_path'

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    puts "TOPICS PARAMS",params[:topic_id]
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @comments = @topic.comments

    @comment = current_user.comments.build( comment_params )
    @comment.topic = @topic
    @new_comment = Comment.new

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was created."
      redirect_to topics_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the comment. Please try again."
      redirect_to topics_path
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :topic_id)
  end
end
```

All of this is rendered in the topics#index path, so here is the topics controller as well.

```
topics_controller.rb

class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @topics = Topic.order(created_at: :desc)
    @comments = Comment.all
    @limited_partners = LimitedPartner.all
    @users = User.all
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
    @topic.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @topic.limited_partner_id = current_user.limited_partner_id if current_user
    if @topic.save
      flash[:notice] = "Topic was saved successfully."
      redirect_to topics_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  private
  def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(:body, :liked, :limited_partner_id, :user_id, :comment_id)
  end
end
```

In the index.html.haml file I call the partial like this:

```
= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: topic, comment: @comment}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `remote: true` for your form. So the submit will trigger an Ajax request. A javascript response will be returned, but no HTML will be updated by default.

You will need to sprinkle some javascript to update the HTML yourself: [bind a callback to the `ajax:success` event](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for), or [use a js view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example) (e.g. `app/views/comments/create.js.erb`).

Have also a look at [Turbolinks 3](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) (still in development), which can reduce the amount of custom javascript required for partial page updates.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem likely lies here ...

```
= form_for [topic, Comment.new], remote: true do |f|
```

Try this instead

```
= form_for @new_comment, url: {controller: 'comments', action: 'create'}, method: "post", remote: true do
```

and be sure your config/routes.rb looks something like this

```
get "/some-path", to: "comments#create"
post "/some-path", to: "comments#create"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use javascript to get better control over the form and data.  So I made a topic.coffee file with this:

```
$ ->
  $('.new_comment').on 'submit', (event) =>
    form = $(event.target).closest('form')
    topicCommentsId = form.attr('action').replace(/\//g, '_').substring(1)
    owningCommentsSection = $('#' + topicCommentsId)
    formData = form.serialize()
    $.post form.attr('action'), formData, (data) =>
      extractedBody = $(data.substring(data.indexOf('<body')))
      topicComments = extractedBody.find('#' + topicCommentsId)
      owningCommentsSection.html(topicComments.html())
      form.find('[name="comment[body]"]').val('')
      location.reload();
    return false
```

I removed the remote: true from my form as well and identify each topic in my index.html.haml with this:

```
.f-grid-row.topic_comments{id: "topics_#{topic.id}_comments"}
    - topic.comments.each do |comment|
        - if comment.topic_id == topic.id || comment.post_id == topic.id
            ...
```